# Cannot get value of getter in OnMapReady (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android-studio, google-maps, android-maps

Im trying to get realtime location with pointing on the Google Map. Currently i successfully get the latitude and longitude in realtime and it will update everytime to a getter, setter `class` called `sosrecord.getLatitude()` and `sosrecord.getLongitude()`. I want to point the google map based on the updated latitude and longitude. But everytime when i put the getter on the `LatLng latLng = new LatLng(sosrecord.getLatitude(), sosrecord.getLongitude());` it will return me Null and eventually crash the app due to    `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference` It should point the current location when user click on a button. Sorry if the code sample below is messy, hope someone could help me with this issue. Thanks.

**Main.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    DatabaseReference reff;
    SosRecords sosrecords;
    boolean startclicked =true;
    String selectedOfficer = "Police";
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    int LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE = 1001;
    SupportMapFragment smf;



    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    LocationRequest locationRequest; 
    LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult   <------This function will get the lat and long and set the value to sosrecordlocationResult) {
            if (locationResult == null) {
                return;
            }
            for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                double lat = location.getLatitude();
                double lon = location.getLongitude();
                sosrecords.setLatitude(lat);
                sosrecords.setLongitude(lon);

            }
        }
    };


    private void showOptionDialog() {
        String[] officers = {"Police", "Hospital", "Bomba"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Choose SOS types");
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(officers, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                selectedOfficer = officers[which];
            }
        });
        builder.setPositiveButton("Proceed", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                sosrecords.setCallFor(selectedOfficer);{
                    onStart();
                    startclicked= false;
                    //GET ALL INFORMATION FROM FIRESTORE AND SEND TO REALTIME DATABASE
                    if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()!= null){
                        DocumentReference df = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users").document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                        df.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                                if(documentSnapshot.getString("FullName")!= null){
                                    String id = reff.push().getKey();
                                    Log.d(TAG, "asdasd"+id);
                                    SosRecords sosRecords = new SosRecords(documentSnapshot.getString("FullName"), (documentSnapshot.getString("PhoneNumber")), (documentSnapshot.getString("UserEmail") ),sosrecords.getLatitude(),sosrecords.getLongitude(),sosrecords.getCallFor() );
                                    reff.child(id).setValue(sosRecords);
                                    sosrecords.setRecordID(id);
                                    btnStartSOS.setEnabled(false);
                                    btnStopSOS.setEnabled(true);
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You're are now activating SOS request !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    LatLonLoop.run();
                                    smf.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                                            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(sosrecords.getLatitude(),sosrecords.getLongitude());
                                            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Here");

                                            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                                            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,15));
                                        }
                                    });

                                }

                            }


                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class));
                                finish();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        checkSettingsAndStartLocationUpdates();
                    }else{
                        askLocationPermission();
                    }


                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

**My get/set class**

```
package com.example.sossystem;

public class SosRecords {

    String RecordID;
    String FullName;
    String PhoneNumber;
    String EmailAddress;
    Double Latitude;
    Double Longitude;
    String CallFor;


    public SosRecords(){

    }



    public SosRecords(String fullName, String phoneNumber, String userEmail, Double latitude, Double longitude, String callFor) {

        FullName = fullName;
        PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        EmailAddress = userEmail;
        Latitude = latitude;
        Longitude = longitude;
        CallFor = callFor;
    }

    public String getRecordID() {
        return RecordID;
    }

    public void setRecordID(String recordID) {
        RecordID = recordID;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return FullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        FullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return PhoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return EmailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        EmailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public Double getLatitude() {
        return Latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
        Latitude = latitude;
    }

    public Double getLongitude() {
        return Longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
        Longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getCallFor() {
        return CallFor;
    }

    public boolean setCallFor(String callFor) {
        CallFor = callFor;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that when you open MainActiity that time **onMapReady()** called first automatically before **LocationCallback**. Eventually, it will return null latitude and Longitude.

However, your problem is that you haven't assigned your map fragment.

**first of all,** you need to assign in **onLocationResult()** below the for loop.

```
 SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
 supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(MapsActivity.this);
```

**Secondly,** remove smf.getMapAsync() from onMapReady().

**Instead of,**

```
smf.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(sosrecords.getLatitude() 
                          ,sosrecords.getLongitude());
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions(). 
                              position(latLng).title("Here");

googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                                        
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,15));
}
});
```

**Replace,**

```
// declare googlemap as a globally
private GoogleMap mMap;
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
mMap = googleMap;
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(sosrecords.getLatitude() 
                          ,sosrecords.getLongitude());
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions(). 
                              position(latLng).title("Here");

googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                                        
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,15));
}
});
```

Comment: Im still getting null when i replace it to `SosRecords sosrecords = new SosRecords();`

Comment: Actually i can get anything outside the `OnMapReady` method, but inside this method it only return null

Comment: can i copy the object and copy to another object `sosrecord2`. Then i use `sosrecord2` in `OnMapReady` method ?

Comment: I already able to get my latitude and longitude in realtime. But i coulnt call my object `sosrecord.getLatitude` and `sosrecord.getLongitude` in the OnMapReady method. So what i was thinking is am i able to copy the first `sosrecord` object to another object call `sosrecord2` and use it in OnMapReady method

Comment: why you are using for loop in onLocationResult()  if you want only last location you don't need for loop.

Comment: I need to loop cause i need to get realtime update of my Latitude and longitude

Comment: you call me to remove the `, remove smf.getMapAsync()` from onMapReady(). But whenever i delete it , the `googleMap` become error with red hightlight

Comment: check my answer now I updated onMapReady().

Comment: I still couldn't solve it based on your explanation, are you free to have a TeamViewer session with  me ?

Comment: I think its better if we could chat privately. Do you have any social media account ? I will give you my Teamviewer id on the chat instead at here

Comment: you are in linkedin ?

Comment: Yeah add me (http://linkedin.com/in/zhuang-ah-8445b3211)